# React strict mode breaks application in development with OAuth

Tags: reactjs

In my OAuth flow, the token can only be called once, then it 404's. In React strict mode, it renders my component twice, which invokes a call to my back-end. The second call invalidates my token. This is a pain when developing (I know this is disabled in production). Is there a viable workaround? I've tried this state hack, but it doesn't work.

```
  const [code, setCode] = useState("")
  useEffect(() => {
    setCode("active")
    if (code == "") {
      forwardAuthCode();
    }
  }, [code])
```

The function invocation makes a back-end call to redeem the token from the auth code in OAuth.